# Android Gradle include module dependencies in another module

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I am using the latest Android Studio 3.0.0-beta6 to build my Android project and there's this dependency issue.
`Gradle` encouraged me to replace all `compile's` with `implementation's`. Here's my project structure:

Project:

- module1

  - module2

Module1 depends on some libraries, module2 depends on module1. However, the libraries from module1 are not visible in module2. I don't want to copy-paste dependencies and would rather have the library dependencies declared only once. Is there a simple solution to this? Thank you.

module1's build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    ...
}
```

module2's build gradle:

```
implementation project(':module1')
```

Comment: so to understand better you have some common dependencies for modules 1 and 2 correct?

Comment: yes. 1 and 2 have common dependencies.

Comment: this is easy!! Just put your common dependencies in the Root Project -> build.gradle and they will apply for all your modules

Comment: But I don't want it in all my modules, just these 2.

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Root Project -> build.gradle you should have something like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Add dependencies there!!

**UPDATE**

If you do not want all your modules to have the common dependencies but only specific modules then do this:

1. Create a folder in your Root Project/gradleScript
2. Create a .gradle file in this folder (e.g. gradleScript/dependencies.gradle)
   that looks like:

   ```
   ext {

   //Version

   supportLibrary = '22.2.1'

   //Support Libraries dependencies
   supportDependencies = [
           design           :         "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}",
           recyclerView     :         "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
           cardView         :         "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
           appCompat        :         "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}",
           supportAnnotation:         "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibrary}",
   ]
   }
   ```
3. In your root project build.gradle add this line:

   ```
   buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
   }
   }

   // Load dependencies
   apply from: 'gradleScript/dependencies.gradle'
   ```
4. In your modules accordingly add this:

   ```
   // Module build file

   dependencies {
       //......
       compile supportDependencies.appCompat
       compile supportDependencies.design
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Such a nice solution. Can we use **environment variables** in `apply from` part? Like `apply from: '%projects_root%/gradleScript/dependencies.gradle'`

Comment: the gradleScript folder is in your project dir directly. where the app module folder is. If you want to prevent it from others to see it then add it in .gitignore I would suggest. But if you really want environment variables you can try this: for example : `println System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')`

Comment: this approach doesn't show upgrade version warning https://miro.medium.com/max/3708/1*hgOycRk5Rds-gOS80Hz6IA.png

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but it sounds to me like what you're after is simply to use `api` instead of `implementation` in your gradle files?

If a module X declares an `api` dependency, it's transitively available to any other module that depends on X. If it however declares an `implementation` dependency, the classes from that dependency is put on the class path for module X, but not for any modules in turn depending on module X.

From Gradle's [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation):

> Dependencies appearing in the api configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers. Dependencies found in the implementation configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath.

So to be concrete:

module 1:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    ...
}
```

module 2:

```
implementation project(':module1')
```

Isn't this the simplest solution to what you're trying to do?

Comment: What if `api` is not an options for some reason

Comment: The other answer if fine, but this should be the accepted answer. Upvoted!