# How to use a variable for android section of build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46527260/811785), I realized that we can use Gradle variables (I'm not familiar with Gradle of course, so excuse my terminology) to make some consistencies across many Android projects.

For example, I want to change the `android` closure configuration from this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

To this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion configurationVariables.sdk
    buildToolsVersion configurationVariables.buildToolsVersion    
  defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion configurationVariables.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion configurationVariables.targetSdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

However, I get this error:

> Error:(5, 0) startup failed: build file
>   'path_to_android\build.gradle': 5: Statement labels may not be used in
>   build scripts. In case you tried to configure a property named
>   'buildToolsVersion', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will
>   not have the desired effect.  @ line 5, column 24.
>          buildToolsVersion: configurationVariables.buildToolsVersion

How can I use variables to centralize my build configuration across projects and modules?

**Update**: I'm defining my `configurationVariables` as follow:

```
ext {

    configurationVariables = [
            sdk = 27,
            buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3",
            minSdk = 16,
            targetSdk = 27
    ]
}
```

I write this in a `config.gradle` file and use `apply from` to import it in the `build.gradle` of the *root project* to apply it on all subprojects.

Comment: how have you defined `configurationVariables`?

Answer (score 1):

your config file structure store value as a varible. Generally this structure is use to store variable.Your config file should be like this

```
ext {


        sdk = 27
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdk = 16
        targetSdk = 27

}
```

and you use this variable as

`compileSdkVersion sdk
 buildToolsVersion buildToolsVersion`

I haven't use array for storing this variable but as you given in another answer link they store array variable with colon(:) and you are directly storing values. I am not sure but try to use colon like this if you want to use an array :

```
ext {
configurationVariables = [
        sdk : 27,
        buildToolsVersion : "27.0.0",
        minSdk : 16,
        targetSdk : 27
]
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion doesn't build at all, because of those commas at the end. Yet I tried them without comma, and still the same error. I tried the array with colon, still the same error.

Comment: yes in first suggestion there is comma which should be removed from that. I tried second method of array and it is working fine for me. Maybe there some other problem in your build file.